# HTML Email Displays Incorrectly In Outlook

Tags: email

We have been using MyEmma to do email campaigns. Everything had been work but about 2 weeks ago HTML emails have not been displaying correctly within our organization. So when I look at an email sent to my work email address using Outlook it does not display correctly. If I have the same email sent to my Gmail or Hotmail account it displays correctly. If I forward the email to my work email address from my Gmail or Hotmail it displays correctly. Everyone at work has the same display problem. Any ideas as to what would cause the problem or advice on troubleshooting would be helpful.

Comment: On a broad level i would say its the method of coding that's involved. Without the email code it is pretty hard to give an answer as to why its happening.

Comment: Hey, like Syfer said you have something wrong with your code. Post it here and I will fix it for you